# Stop 'Turn on sync...' Prompt in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Every time I create a bookmark, Chromium/Chrome displays a prompt to turn on sync. I don't want to do this and it's getting annoying. Is there some setting which will disable this prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I stumbled across:

Settings > Sync and Google services > Allow Chromium/Chrome sign-in > Off